# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: not working in a NSPanel?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've a strange situation.

I've subclassed a NSTableview with some customised code.
I've a tableView in a NSWindow inheriting from this subclass. And another tableView in a NSPanel which is opening over the window.

In the subclass I call a method with the function `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

The method is successfully call for the table in the NSWindow, but it's not for the table in the NSPanel.

If I call directly the method (without using the delay function), instead it works. Therefore it seems that `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` fails to work in the NSPanel.

Any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSPanel is likely running modally, with it's own event loop, so try [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:) with `@[NSDefaultRunLoopMode, NSModalPanelRunLoopMode]` as the inModes parm.

See [`runModalForWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/runModalForWindow:) for the gist of the event loop stuff.

Same issue [reported here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/282836-performselector-doesn-work-for-modal-window.html).